# Resource booking in multiple meeting rooms

Tags: civibooking

Is Civibooking designed to allow LIMITED resources to be booked in multiple meeting rooms at the same time?

For example, I have 10 chairs. I booked 5 of the chairs for an event in meeting room X, between 09:00 till 10:00. I then booked the remaining chairs in meeting room Y, also between 09:00 till 10:00. In civibookng calendar, this is not possible! It refuses to allow the booking at the same time. It forgets that the remaining chairs can be book at the same time, but in different rooms. Is the extension designed to work that way, and thus use Configuration Set to mimic booking times? Or I am missing something?